# Collaborative Latex

Tags: latex

I would like to insert **notes** on the fixes to be done in specific places of my latex document
and maybe have a **list** of "todos/fixme"

How do you handle this?

Seems one way is to use the fixme package, but I couldn't make it work.

Is Anyone using it?

Comment: What LaTeX distriution are you running? How did you try to install?

Comment: Latest MacTex, just added \usepackage{fixme}

Comment: You have all dependencies (xspace, ifthen, verbatim, xkeyval), right?
What exactly is not working? Is it compiling or do "just" the commands not what they ought to?

Comment: It's a bit late, but I stumbled over a related question at [mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3044/tools-for-collaborative-paper-writing)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another option is the [todonotes](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/) package which works very well. Just add `\usepackage{todonotes}` in your preamble.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks